# get total number of elements in a multidimensional array using std::extent

Tags: c++, c++11

How to find total number of elements in a multidimensional array using std::extent. This is my sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    int32_t int_arr[10][100][1000];
    int32_t no_of_elements = 1;
    
    // compiler error in below for loop block
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < std::rank<decltype(int_arr)>{}; ++i)
        no_of_elements *= std::extent<decltype(int_arr), i>{};
        
    no_of_elements *= std::extent<decltype(int_arr), 0>{};
    no_of_elements *= std::extent<decltype(int_arr), 1>{};
    no_of_elements *= std::extent<decltype(int_arr), 2>{};
    std::cout << no_of_elements << std::endl;

    std::cout << sizeof(int_arr) / sizeof(std::remove_all_extents<decltype(int_arr)>::type) << std::endl;
        
    return 0;
}
```

`error: the value of ‘i’ is not usable in a constant expression 9 |   no_of_elements *= std::extent<decltype(int_arr), i>{};`

Comment: You get the error message, because ````std::extend```` expects N as a compile time constant, as usual for templates. You cannot put in runtime values. That does not work. You need to employ template meta programming or constexpr functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With C++14 `std::index_sequence`, you can use `std::extent` with something like:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr std::size_t count_elements(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return (1 * ... * std::extent<T, Is>{}); // C++17 fold expression
                                             // Alternatives exist for C++11/C++14
}

template <typename T>
constexpr std::size_t count_elements()
{
    return count_elements<T>(std::make_index_sequence<std::rank<T>{}>());
}

int main()
{
    int32_t int_arr[10][100][1000];
    int32_t no_of_elements = count_element<decltype(int_arr)>();

    std::cout << no_of_elements << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: All other answers are good, but that is the way to go. Because the OP wanted to use ````std::extend````. You could add a convenience constexpr wrapper function and hand over the variable name 'int_arr' as reference parameter and then use ````std::remove_reference<decltype(c)>::type```` as type. And additionally my fold expression looks like ````return ((std::extent<Container, (dimensions)>{}) * ...);````. Without the 1* and ````std::integer_sequence````

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler way is to get the type of array element and then `sizeof(array)/sizeof(element)` is an answer:

```
int32_t int_arr[10][100][1000];
using element = std::remove_all_extents<decltype(int_arr)>::type;
no_of_elements = sizeof(int_arr)/sizeof(element);
```

So use [`remove_all_extents`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_all_extents)

in templated version (like in C++14 variable template):

```
template <typename ArrayType>
constexpr std::size_t no_of_elements_v = 
  sizeof(ArrayType) / sizeof(remove_all_extents_t<ArrayType>;
```

---

If you really insist on using C++11 and std::extent - this is the solution:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t rank = std::rank<T>{}, std::size_t dim = 0>
struct NumOfElements :
  std::integral_constant<std::size_t, std::extent<T, dim>{} * NumOfElements<T, rank, dim + 1>::value>
{};

template <typename T, std::size_t rank>
struct NumOfElements<T, rank, rank> :
  std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1u>
{};
```

And use `NumOfElements<decltype(int_arr)>::value`

But much, much simpler is this simple template version w/o any type_traits, if you replace integral_constant with simple static member variable - it should work even in pre-C++11:

```
template <typename T>
struct NumOfElements : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1u>
{};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct NumOfElements<T[N]> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 
    N * NumOfElements<T>::value>
{};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
 
template<class A>
size_t getSize(const A&)
{
    typedef typename std::remove_all_extents<A>::type Type;
    return sizeof(A) / sizeof(Type);
}
 
int main()
{
    int a1[3][10];
    float a2[5][10][10];
    double a3[3][10];
    std::int32_t int_arr[10][100][1000];
 
    std::cout << "Size of array a1: " << getSize(a1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Size of array a2: " << getSize(a2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Size of array a3: " << getSize(a3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Size of array int_arr: " << getSize(int_arr) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Size of array a1: 30
Size of array a2: 500
Size of array a3: 30
Size of array int_arr: 1000000
```

One minus of this code is function getSize() is generated for each type of array:

```
type of a1: int[3][10] (GCC outputs: A3_A10_i)
type of a2: float[5][10][10] (GCC outputs: A5_A10_A10_f)
type of a3: double[3][10] (GCC outputs: A3_A10_d)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `std::extent` is the right choice here. I'd simply define a "recursive" template:

```
template<typename T>
struct nested_array_size
{
    static constexpr size_t value = 1;
};

template<typename T, size_t N>
struct nested_array_size<T[N]>
{
    static constexpr size_t value = N * nested_array_size<T>::value;
};
```

```
std::cout << nested_array_size<double[1][2][3][4]>::value << std::endl;
std::cout << nested_array_size<int[5]>::value << std::endl;
std::cout << nested_array_size<int[5][6]>::value << std::endl;
```

Comment: I think, ````std::extend```` is a very good and intuitive choice. With ````std::integer_sequence```` no problem at all. See answer from Jarod42